# How to join vertical and horizontal table together table

Tags: postgresql, join, entity-attribute-value

I have two table with one of them is vertical i.e store only key value pair with ref id from table 1. i want to join both table and dispaly key value pair as a column in select. and also perform sorting on few keys. 
T1 having (id,empid,dpt)
T2 having (empid,key,value)

```
select 
    T1.*,
    t21.value,
    t22.value,
    t23.value,
    t24.value

from    Table1 t1
join    Table2 t21 on t1.empid = t21.empid
join    Table2 t22 on t1.empid = t22.empid
join    Table2 t23 on t1.empid = t23.empid

where   
        t21.key = 'FNAME'
    and t22.key = 'LNAME'
    and t23.key='AGE'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query)

Answer (score 2):

The query you demonstrate is very inefficient (another join for each additional column) and also has a potential problem: if there isn't a row in `T2` for *every* key in the `WHERE` clause, the whole row is excluded.

The second problem can be avoided with `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN` instead of `[INNER] JOIN`. But don't bother, the solution to the first problem is a completely different query. "Pivot" `T2` using `crosstab()` from the additional module `tablefunc`:

```sql
SELECT * FROM crosstab(
       'SELECT empid, key, value FROM t2 ORDER  BY 1'
    , $$VALUES ('FNAME'), ('LNAME'), ('AGE')$$  -- more?
   ) AS ct (empid int      -- use *actual* data types
          , fname text
          , lname text
          , age   text);
          -- more?
```

Then just join to `T1`:

```
select *
from   t1
JOIN  (<insert query from above>) AS t2 USING (empid);
```

This time you may want to use `[INNER] JOIN`.

The `USING` clause conveniently removes the second instance of the `empid` column.

Detailed instructions:

- [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905)